# Сайт остается не доверенным после установки ssl

Tags: https, ssl

Добрый день. Первый опыт по установке ssl сертификата на сервер. Сгенерил через startssl.ru бесплатный dv сертификат, залил на тачку, настроил nginx. Но при заходе на сайт https всё равно горит красным и выскакивает сообщение о том, что сайт не доверенный. ssl-чекеры говорят, что серт в порядке и никаких проблем нет. В статьях нашёл, что это возникает, если на сайт подгружается контент через http, но у меня пустая страница, на которой даже скриптов нет. Кто подскажет, в чём может быть проблема?

конфиг

```
server {

listen 80 default_server;
listen 443 ssl;

root /var/www/html/yoom.team/web/;
index app_dev.php;
server_name 176.112.223.254 yoom.team www.yoom.team;

access_log /var/log/yoom.team/access.log;
error_log /var/log/yoom.team/error.log;

ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/yoom.team/yoom.team.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/yoom.team/private.key;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ / break;
}

location ~ ^/(.*).(js|css|png|jpeg|jpg|html) {
    root /var/www/html/yoom.team/web/;
}

location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index app_dev.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
}
```

}

upstream php-fpm {
    server unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

результат проверки на ssllabs  https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=yoom.team

**РЕШЕНИЕ:**

Проблема была в том, что сертификаты StartSSl считаются теперь не валидными.
Поставил сертификат Let's Encrypt.

Comment: Конфиг nginx прикрепите в тело вопроса. И что показывает при проверке https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: Нет промежуточных сертификатов до корневого. Они должны быть в nginx. Посмотрите в браузере статус сертификата - увидите, чего не хватает.

Comment: а лучше просто дай ссылку на сайт

Comment: ссылка на сайт yoom.team

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=yoom.team

Comment: цепочка сертификатов не корректная и используются компроментируемые протоколы

Comment: что значит не корректная цепочка? рут, промежуточный и серт сайта в неправильном порядке следуют?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79519/ssl-tls-how-to-fix-chain-issues-contains-anchor

Comment: удалил из цепочки root сертификат, проблема сохраняется

Comment: можете разъяснить эту строчку конфига?                             ssl_trusted_certificate = StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA + StartCom Certification Authority         Это промужуточный серт плюс что?

Comment: @norbornen Рестартанул nginx,  этой проблемы больше нет, но озеленить https это не помогло

Comment: какая версия nginx?

Comment: Это не строчки конфига (с плюсом), а пояснение, что файл public.crt должен содержать два сертификата, и файл my-chain.pem должен содержать тоже два.

Comment: @KAGGDesign какие сертификаты должны лежать в my-chain.pem?

Comment: @norbornen nginx 1.10.0

Comment: так он же написал, какие должны лежать. Но не суть - главное, чтобы nginx видел всю цепочку. У меня два сертификата в одном файле .pem - моего сайта и промежуточный. Т.е. так выглядит: ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/kagg.pem;    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/kagg.key;

Comment: @KAGGDesign повторюсь, в yoom.team.crt лежат сертификат сайта и промежуточный сертификат. Это ssl_certificate параметр в nginx. Нужен ли ssl_trusted_certificate параметр и какие сертификаты там должны лежать? что такое " StartCom Certification Authority"

Comment: если лежат, то конфиг в порядке. Я привел две строчки из своего конфига - больше у меня нет ничего про сертификаты, все работает. Проблема, видимо, в том, что Google перестал признавать сертификаты StartCom

Comment: @KAGGDesign подскажите, где тогда лучше купить сертификат?

Comment: Я использую CloudFlare, они не только предоставляют услуги CDN (есть бесплатный тариф), но и дают бесплатный сертификат на 15 лет. Единственное ограничение - управление DNS должно быть перенесено на CloudFlare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл `/etc/ssl/yoom.team/yoom.team.crt` должен содержать два сертификата - вашего сайта и промежуточный - `StartCom Class 1 DV Server CA`.

Но это общая рекомендация.

А в данном конкретном случае, следует отказаться от сертификатов StartCom, выпущенных позднее 21 октября 2016, потому что Google перестал их считать валидными: https://geektimes.ru/post/285142/

Comment: спасибо, вопрос снят

Comment: Если ответ полезный, его можно отметить, как принятый (зеленая галочка). Это позволит ориентироваться посетителям, которые ищут ответ на свой похожий вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Вы вложили в /etc/ssl/yoom.team/yoom.team.crt только сертификат, но не положили промежуточный. Вот дока по теме: https://nginx.ru/ru/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains
2. У вас есть море статики подключенной по http (без ssl) и вероятно ваш браузер ее не грузит и ругается подобным образом.
3. Еще я вижу что там сертифкикат от StartCom. Если это бесплатный серт, то его могут "любить" далеко не все браузеры

Comment: В yoom.team.crt лежат серт сайта и промежуточный. На сайте нет никакой статики вообще. Серт бесплатный, но он не зеленый ни в одном браузере.

Comment: А у меня зеленый) во всех браузерах (Windows 10 и Debian 8). А что в Вашем браузере видно по информации сертификата?

Comment: Я уже поставил сертификат let's encrypt)) Спасибо)